# Стоит ли использовать формы Django (в частности виджеты)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mvc

В Django довольно хорошо реализована работа с формами.
Основная их задача - это сохранение и валидация данных.

Но у них есть ещё много вкусняшек.
Самая значимая - это виджеты, которые позволяют указывать дополнительные атрибуты к полям формы. В дальнейшем весь этот функционал позволяет вывести её на страницу одним тегом `{{ form }}`

---

***Вопрос в следующем:***

> А стоит ли вообще использовать виджеты?

Задался я этим вопросом не случайно.
Начну свои размышления с того, что Django - MVC фреймворк. По всем заветам, при работе с Django желательно отделять  <s>мух от котлет</s> модель, логику сайта и представление.

Но виджеты (как и некоторые другие особенности форм), по моему мнению, смешивают логику сайта с представлением.

*UPD: По большей степени я имею в виду указание классов и атрибутов, вроде `placeholder`, для тегов через виджеты.*

---

#### Удобно ли это?

Риторический вопрос. Смотря для кого.

Если fullstack делать сайт-визитку, то да.
Но, как мне кажется, в больших командах это может затруднить взаимодействие с верстальщиком или ответственным за шаблоны. Не думаю, что эти люди охотно полезут разбираться в `forms.py`.

---

Хотелось бы услышать Ваши мнения по этому вопросу, чтобы не допустить ошибку на этапе архитектуры приложения и выработать паттерн работы с формами, если его ещё нет.

***P. S.:***
Я понимаю, что этот вопрос потенциально может породить некоторую дискуссию, но не считаю, что ответы на него могут быть основаны только на мнении отвечающего. Призываю в большей степени к оперированию существующими паттернами проектирования.

Comment: Смотря что у Вас делают изначально: бек или фронт. У нас, например, сначала делается фронт, вёрстка и только потом уже подгоняется бек под неё. Если видишь в вёрстке какой-то `placeholder`, например, то бек-разработчику не составит труда прописать его в виджет. Если же поле должно быть `required`, то это фронтовщику и не нужно знать, это бек делает. Ну а если у Вас сначала пилится бек, а потом фронт от него отталкивается, тогда, конечно, фронтовщику придётся лазить в формы джанговские и смотреть на виджеты. Не сказал бы, что это удобно, но и сложного ничего там нет, если фронтовщик с головой.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Ваш ответ мне понятен. Увы, но у меня в проекте предлагается совместная параллельная работа. Интересно, что делать в таком случае. _P. S.: Насчёт `required`, я имел в виду атрибут тега `<input>`, неудачный у меня пример._

Comment: Думаю, в таком случае нужно между собой обсудить и придти к единому консенсусу - решить, как делать формы. Через `forms` (тут нужно понимать, знает ли фронтовщик Джанго, если да - то насколько хорошо; есть ли у него желание разобраться с джанговскими формами; насколько этот человек обучаем вообще), или же через `html/css` (тут вопросы аналогичны к бекендеру). _P.S. По поводу `required` - мне кажется, фронтовщику вообще необязательно знать, какие поля в форме являются обязательными - ему главное верстку сделать, а за функционал уже бек отвечает._

Comment: Иногда не удаётся достичь взаимного консенсуса. Никто не хочет делать лишнюю работу (если не брать в расчёт энтузиастов :) ). Поэтому я и хочу услышать мнение как можно большего числа людей, которые занимаются Django-разработкой. Если за мной (или за TL) будет решающий голос, то должен же он быть на чём-то основан.

Comment: Значит, нужно чем-то мотивировать одну из сторон))

Comment: Лично я не использую ни формы, ни виджеты как раз из-за такого смешивания. Навелосипедил себе собственный слой валидации на базе Cerberus и рад (но вряд ли такой вариант подходит остальным)

Answer (score 6):

Стоит использовать виджеты. В основном стандартными. Нестандартные писать только если это действительно нужно и стандартные не подходят.

> Но виджеты (как и некоторые другие особенности форм), по моему мнению, смешивают логику сайта с представлением.

Django - это фреймворк, в основе которого лежит [MTV (Model Template View)](https://djbook.ru/ch05s02.html).

> V определено для «Представления» (View), слоя бизнес-логики. Этот слой содержит логику, как получать доступ к моделям и применять соответствующий шаблон. Вы можете рассматривать его как мост между моделями и шаблонами.

Именно на этом слое происходит основаня работа с формами. Мы выбираем какая форма будет выводиться, как обрабатываться. Для удобства и поддержания порядка, формы выносят в `forms.py` файлы, а свои виджеты выносят в `widgets.py` (а иногда вся в куче).

[О виджетах](https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/forms/widgets.html)

> Виджет – это представление поля в виде HTML кода. Виджеты обеспечивают генерацию HTML и извлечение соответствующих данных из GET/POST запросов.

Это тоже логика, важно правильно извлекать данные из запросов и выводить правильное поле. Написать один раз и использовать везде, а не копипастить в `templates` проекта/приложения в каждой форме. Для примера возьмем поле FK, значения которого подгружаются по AJAX и выводят Подробную информацию об объекте, по причине схожести вариантов. Стандартными средствами django, сейчас это сделать нельзя, но написав после и widget, который будет выводить в атрибуте поля ссылку, откуда брать данные по AJAX, приведет FK поле в рабочий вид. Останется к форме прицепить js обработчик, который сделает остальную работу.

> UPD: По большей степени я имею в виду указание классов и атрибутов, вроде placeholder, для тегов через виджеты

А где еще их выводить? Не в шаблоне же. Это атрибуты поля, а поле выводится через виджеты. А учитывая недавний [вопрос про кастомный placeholder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998694/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-placeholder/998716#998716), переопределение шаблона стандартного поля очень даже удобное решение, чем строить костыли.

> Но, как мне кажется, в больших командах это может затруднить взаимодействие с верстальщиком или ответственным за шаблоны. Не думаю, что эти люди охотно полезут разбираться в forms.py.

Верстальщик выдаст готовый html. Не нравится поле - переопределит его шаблон.
А писать несколько форм с нестандартным представлением поля и копипастить - только заготовки проблем на будущие изменения.

> Я попробовал полностью перенести одну форму в forms.py и был немного обескуражен тем, что у меня получилось в итоге. Это заняло намного больше строк, чем я думал (в разы больше, чем в шаблоне). Но самое главное - это невероятно сильно замусорило чистый и элегантный Python код. Предлагаю Вам самим это оценить на примере указания placeholder

А что мешает написать декоратор, который сам запихнет в них placeholder'ы ? Ну а если отличаются от label, то лучше в одной форме, чем в нескольких шаблонах.

> Так как паттерна я не нашёл (может его и вовсе нет), а мнения людей расплывчатые и сильно расходятся, может возникнуть ситуация с трудностями по поиску кода в проекте. Все разработчики должны без труда находить интересующие их участки кода, а если они потенциально могут находиться в разных файлах, то стоит избегать такую неопределённость.

Трудностей нет. Интересующая форма -> Поле -> Виджет (стандартный или нет) -> Узнаем какой шаблон. Современные IDE (`PyCharm`) позволяют пройти этот путь зажав `CTRL` и тыкая на `ЛКМ`.

Answer (score 2):

Верстальщики и не должны интересоваться `forms.py`, это работа джанго-разработчика.

В формах инкапсулируется работа с данными, точнее работа по вводу данных. Клиент же не должен их валидировать, так как в любом случае этим обязан заниматься сервер. Сервер должен их валидировать сам во-первых потому, что поступающие данные с клиента можно и подделать, а во-вторых клиент не должен знать как работает серверная часть.

Если же в виджете будет определяться оформление форм и их стилистика, то это тоже ошибка, так как вы берёте на себя работу верстальщика. Пускай верстальщик сам определяет как будут располагаться поля и какого размера будут шрифты в своём коде, а не в коде джанги.

**В разработке есть два подхода:**

Если фронт разрабатывается одним проектом с бекендом, то фронтенщику достаточно знать шаблонизатор и дальше шаблонизатора им в бекенд лезть не следует. Заменить виджет, или написать нужный, может и сам джанго-разработчик, в конце-концов все джанго-разработчики - это веб-разработчики.

Если же клиент разрабатывается отдельным приложением, то использовать формы особого смысла нет, работу с данными можно инкапсулировать в сериализаторах `django-rest-framwork`.

Comment: Вы упускаете такой нюанс, что верстальщики *вынуждены* интересоваться `forms.py`, потому что он содержит в себе виджеты, а виджеты содержат в себе вёрстку, и эта вёрстка иногда настраивается как раз через `forms.py`. До версии 1.11 вся вёрстка вообще записывалась прямо в Python-коде :(

Comment: @andreymal, да какая там вёрстка? Там скорее логика работы поля ввода данных.

Comment: Ну и какое отношение упомянутый в вопросе `placeholder` имеет отношение к логике работы?)

Comment: @andreymal, я считаю, что этот атрибут определяет не форму, а содержание.

Comment: А если в виджете описан `class` или `id` какого-либо тега? Или же, не дай бог, атрибут `style`. Можно интерпретировать вопрос так: _"Где стоит верстать форму? В `forms.py` или в шаблонах?"_

Comment: Часть 1:  В forms.py нет никакой верстки, там только логика формы. Вся верстка живет в шаблонах и бех проблем переопледеляется по необходимости. Большую часть параметров, т.ч. и placeholder можно вообще не указывать. Не вижу проблем. Форма в конце концов часть механизма контроля поступающих данных, и функцию свою выполняет. Для верстальщиков - HTML/CSS достаточно. Ну а если уж приспичет расположить поля формы в определнном порядке, то есть замечательный {{ form.<field> }} для вывода поля, или еще более мелкие части полей формы, а именно label и само поле.

Comment: Часть 2:  Не нравится виждет, ну напиши свой, с нужным дизайном и разметкой, но это нужно редко, для случаев вроде color picker. Сами виджеты имеют минимальную разметку и представляются из себя просто select/input и тп поля
Надеюсь я хорошо определил свою точку зрения

Answer (score 2):

Выслушав разные точки зрения, я пришёл к следующему промежуточному мнению:

> Виджеты использовать не стоит (***UPD***: почти)

---

***Аргументы:***

- Не все вообще знают, что это такое :):

Это довольно весомый аргумент, так как frontend-разработчик не интересуется. да и не должен интересоваться фреймворком Django со всеми вытекающими. Максимум, да и то не всегда - это знание шаблонизатора на уровне начинающего. Но моя печальная практика показывает, что некоторые просто забивают на это и перекладывают разработку шаблонов на backender'а, что ставит окончательную точку на идее познакомить frontender'а с формами.

- Трудность поддерживания:

Если вёрстка находится и в `forms.py`, и в `templates/` возникает необходимость поддерживать и связывать 2 файла вместо одного (что нарушает некоторые другие паттерны программирования). Это занимает больше человеко-часов, соответственно ухудшает производительность труда, требует больших экономических затрат *и вот это вот всё со всеми вытекающими :)*

- Трудность поиска:

Так как паттерна я не нашёл (может его и вовсе нет), а мнения людей расплывчатые и сильно расходятся, может возникнуть ситуация с трудностями по поиску кода в проекте. Все разработчики должны без труда находить интересующие их участки кода, а если они потенциально могут находиться в разных файлах, то стоит избегать такую неопределённость.

- Неуклюжесть или же громоздкость:

Я попробовал полностью перенести одну форму в `forms.py` и был немного обескуражен тем, что у меня получилось в итоге. Это заняло намного больше строк, чем я думал (в разы больше, чем в шаблоне). Но самое главное - это невероятно сильно замусорило чистый и элегантный Python код. Предлагаю Вам самим это оценить на примере указания `placeholder`:

```py
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Логин',
    }))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'E-mail',
    }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Пароль',
    }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Повторите пароль',
    }))
    ...
```

**UPD:** Я немного поменял точку зрения, относительно кода Выше, благодаря комментариям пользователя [Мистер Фикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/215517/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81). В действительности, указывать `placeholder` в `forms.py` довольно хорошая идея, так как это касается логики формы. Верстальщик не должен делать предположений насчёт этого, ровно как и пользователь.

---

Для меня этих доводов вполне хватило, чтобы отказаться от виджетов в пользу стандартной `HTML` разметки. Её все знают, при её редактировании не перезагружается сервер, а проблему структуризации решает шаблонизатор. Плюсов не так много, но они хотя бы есть по сравнению с формами. (***UPD:*** Исключением является `placeholder`. Пересмотрев своё мнение, я пришёл к выводу о том, что он относится к логике формы и, пока нет другого способа указывать его, придётся использовать для этого виджеты.)

***P. S.:***
Я всё ещё жду Ваших комментариев и возможных решений. Буду рад услышать мнение каждого!

Comment: Здесь нет вёрстки. Здесь я вижу работу с данными. Клиент понятия не имеет, что за данные в формах и как с ними работать, но зато об этом знает сервер. Нету здесь говнокода, всё по уму. Ещё раз повторю, в формах, в том числе в виджетах, инкапсулирована работа с данными, что вы здесь и продемонстрировали.

Comment: Точнее инкапсулирована работа по вводу данных.

Comment: @МистерФикс Мне потребовался день, чтобы обдумать Вами сказанное. И знаете, я немного поменял точку зрения. А ведь, действительно, порой верстальщик не знает какая логика заложена в форме и какой должен быть `placeholder`. Ваше замечание довольно хорошо. Но вот классов и `CSS` это уже точно не должно касаться, как думаете?

Comment: @МистерФикс Может добавите это в Ваш ответ? Это весомые доводы. Поддержу плюсом :)

Comment: поправил, что пришло на ум. Рад был помочь. Сам тоже сталкиваюсь постоянно, что разработчики не понимают в каких абстракциях и какая именно логика изолируется(инкапсулируется).

Comment: @МистерФикс forms.py намертво приколачивает вёрстку к форме путём прописывания виджета (в данном примере TextInput и EmailInput), и это очень сильно ограничивает полёт фантазии верстальщика.

Comment: @andreymal, а не надо в формах вёрсткой заниматься.

Comment: @МистерФикс это означает необходимость отказаться от виджетов. А если нет виджетов — то зачем и формы? :)

Comment: @andreymal, виджеты не вёрстку определяют, а способ ввода данных.

Comment: @МистерФикс если вы хоть раз писали виджеты или заглядывали в их код, то могли видеть, что в коде виджетов намертво прописываются шаблоны и вёрстка.

Comment: andreymal, то что такая возможность есть, не означает, что есть необходимость в её использовании. Но с её помощью можно например написать хороший виджет с кнопочками для в вода времени или чисел, для которой верстальщик сможет доделать шрифты, цвета и подобное.