# Необходимо позиционировать подсказку внутри placeholder

Tags: html, css

Есть placeholder высотой 200px, и также есть подсказка. Она находится посередине всей формы, а по дизайну должна находиться в верхнем левом углу. Подскажите, можно ли сделать такое с помощью position или другими средствами.

```css
.contact_placeholder {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="contact_placeholder" placeholder="Name">
```

Comment: Именно расположение placeholder вы не сможете изменить. Он поддерживает небольшой ряд свойств. Подробнее почитайте здесь https://html5.by/blog/placeholder/

Answer (score 1):

В хроме работает вот так:

```css
.contact_placeholder {
  height: 200px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: red;
  transform: translateY(-100px) translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="contact_placeholder" placeholder="Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант решения вашего вопроса. Увы, в before нет адекватных способов вставить content

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-wrapper').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.placeholder')
      .html(
        $(this).find('input').attr('placeholder')
      );
  });
});
```

```css
.input-wrapper .placeholder {
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}

.input-wrapper input {
    placeholder: none;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}


input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
/* Firefox < 19 */
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
/* Firefox > 19 */
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

/* Internet Explorer 10 */
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input placeholder="123" />
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```